# woocommerce what table that stores the quantity of product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new in wordpress and woocommerce can someone help me please what table name that stores the product and the quantity ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Products and quantities are located in the following tables; wp_posts and wp_postmeta